# Is it possible to automatically calculate aws user and resources costs?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cost-explorer

I'm working on a solution which will automate user creation in AWS and I would like to also generate a cost report per these created users and all their resources, per month.

So for example, let's say that my solution creates an AWS user for user John, and also a m5.large instance type with 80gb EBS store.
Is that possible to automate the cost calculation of John's account (including instances and other resources created by him)?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is possible using **tags**. You will want to create unique tags based on the dimension you want to measure and assign those to the appropriate resources. Then you can export this information to a CSV or (I think) pull it from CloudWatch. See [Cost Allocation Tags](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/awsaccountbilling/latest/aboutv2/cost-alloc-tags.html).

There is a limit to the number of tags you can use, in a large environment you may want to look at using nested names or some other method to stretch them out (at the cost of additional processing logic when you parse the information).